# Typeerror: cannot set property "password" of null

Tags: javascript, mongodb

having some trouble figuring out why I get this error.
I have tried changing syntax but dont get it right, please help.
I think this is just a syntaxerror.

this is how i send my data

```
const data = { newPassword : newPassword }

const response = await request({ endpoint: `blablabla`, method: "PUT", body: data }
```

this is how i receive the data

```
const {newPassword}  = req.body; 

if(token && newPassword) {
    console.log("token and password exist");
    User.findOne({token: token}).then(user=> {
        console.log("password" + newPassword); //prints out correct password
        user.password = newPassword;
        user.usertoken = "";
        user.save(function(err){
          if(err)return next(err);
          else res.json({message:"Password changed",result:true})
        });
      
    }).catch(next)
  }
  else {
    res.status(400).json({message:"Missing information! The password could not be updated.",result:false})
  }
```

Comment: sounds like findOne did not find a user. Error is complaining that user is null, has nothing to do with the value of newPassword

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` output? I bet on `null`, so it wasn't found in the DB

Comment: You're right, console.log(user) prints out null.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, I think I know the problem

Comment: The user wasn't found in the DB? :)